# Handling zeros in Cramer's V for contingency table

Tags: r, nan, categorical-data, chi-squared

I'm following the vcd docs where `assocstats` is called on an `xtable` call on multiple subsets of a data frame. However, I get NaNs with a specific subset because the expected observations for many cases is 0:

```
        factor.2
factor.1  0  1  2  3  4 5 or more
      0   0 12  7  1  0         1
      1   0  2  1  1  0         0
      2   0  8  2  1  0         0
      3   0  5  4  0  0         0
      4   0  1  2  2  0         0
      5   0  6  8  0  0         0
      6   0  5  3  0  0         0
      7   0  5  1  0  0         0
      8   0  5  4  0  1         0
      9   0  1  1  0  1         0
      10  0  5  6  0  0         1

temp.table <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 
2L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(11L, 6L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    factor.1 = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10"), factor.2 = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5 or more"
    )), .Names = c("factor.1", "factor.2")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(data = cases.limited, na.action = na.omit))

library(vcd)

assocstats(temp.table)

                    X^2 df P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio 35.004 50  0.94676
Pearson             NaN 50      NaN

Phi-Coefficient   : NA 
Contingency Coeff.: NaN 
Cramer's V        : NaN
```

Is there a way to quickly and efficiently avoid including these cases in the analysis without extensive rewriting of some of what `assocstats` or `xtable` do? I understand that there is arguably less statistical power, but Cramer's V is already an optimistic estimator, so the results will still be useful to me.

Comment: Wow, the new UI for dupe votes is excellent. Edited to focus the question on handling the cases, not figuring out the stats.

Comment: very roughly but `assocstats( table + 1.0E-8)`

Comment: That's a decent hack.